# Jupyter notebook !cat: how to limit output

Tags: jupyter-notebook

I would like to use !cat magic in order to view the structure (e.g. number of columns) of a huge file (150 MB). When I simply execute `!cat filename.csv`, Jupyter hangs. Is it possible to specify how many rows to display?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Like it says [here](https://superuser.com/questions/564554/how-to-set-max-line-in-cat-command), `cat` is dedicated to whole files. Using

```
!head filename.csv --lines=100
```

should do the trick.

Comment: Well, unfortunately, there is no such command as !head. I would also like to view pretty much any kinds of files, so it's not always possible to create a DataFrame via read_csv.

Comment: Can I ask what OS you're using?

Comment: I'm using Ubuntu and this is the output of %alias command:
`Total number of aliases: 12
Out[140]:
[('cat', 'cat'),
 ('cp', 'cp'),
 ('ldir', 'ls -F -o --color %l | grep /$'),
 ('lf', 'ls -F -o --color %l | grep ^-'),
 ('lk', 'ls -F -o --color %l | grep ^l'),
 ('ll', 'ls -F -o --color'),
 ('ls', 'ls -F --color'),
 ('lx', 'ls -F -o --color %l | grep ^-..x'),
 ('mkdir', 'mkdir'),
 ('mv', 'mv'),
 ('rm', 'rm'),
 ('rmdir', 'rmdir')]`

Comment: I don't have access to my Ubuntu machine at the moment, but can you try `!cat filename.csv | head`?

Comment: Odd. Can you try `%bash head filename.csv`?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/150656/discussion-between-thedetective-and-makar).

Comment: well, actually the !head command works like a charm. Could you please edit your message a bit, so that I can accept it?

Comment: @makar I edited my answer, let me know if there's anything else you need before you accept.

Answer (score 0):

For ubuntu system Giving error while we use **!cat-path here-**.Use a 'more' before path.
i.e
***`more /home/om/Desktop/data science/ineauron filr/code_pandas1/examples/ex1.csv`*